Weblate GitHub merge request initialization through API request
I would like to automate project translation with each push into the "dev" branch. If the content of translation .yml files is changed, a GitHub action will call Weblate through the API to translate the project.
I have solved this and also automated translations (via API requests), and it works great!
However, when the translation process is finished, I would also like to create a new pull request into the "dev" branch, and at this point, I am lost.
After auto-translating the project, I will execute (via Weblate API) "commit," then I will execute "push." Now (via API), I need to create a pull request. In GitHub, I successfully set the GitHub token. I probably need to somehow execute the process to create a merge request (via Weblate API).
I didn't find the solution in Weblate API documentation: https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/api.html#post--api-components-(string-project)-(string-component)-repository-

You can create a workflow triggered by a push to the branch used by Weblate API. You would want to further restrict the trigger to only changes to the files updated by the API.
on:
  push:
    branches: [api-branch]
    paths:
    - path-edited-by-api/**

This workflow can use GitHub CLI available on ubuntu-latest runners to create a pull request Let me know if you need more info.
.

I didn't thinking by this way, but It can be also the solution. But I don't know, If I can be sure with the branch name comming from Weblate, because the branch name contains name of first component from list of components from the project, I don't know, if it is normal behavior (if Weblate doesn't create another branch itself in the future).

Can you not tell Weblate to use a specific branch ?
